# Kotlin's naming conventions for private values

Tags: kotlin

Have read Kotlin's style guide https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#interface-implementation-layout.

This does not make it clear why IntelliJ IDEA underline "private val LOGGER =" with the suggestion that LOGGER is changed to logger.
This is particularly weird because IDEA doesn't have a problem if private is removed and we leave "val LOGGER =".

In my mind UPPER_CASE should be used if the object is not mutable at any level. Whether it is private or not is irrelevant.

Comment: The linter isn't perfect. You can open a bug report on YouTrack

Comment: Just did that https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-56802/IntelliJ-IDEA-suggest-change-to-UPPERCASE-name-unless-private-is-removed

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell, these three inspections in IntelliJ are responsible for reporting "bad" property names:

[image]

From top to bottom, they are called:

- Object property naming convention
- Private property naming convention
- Property naming convention

Each of them has a regex associated with it. It is as simple as "whatever doesn't match the regex gets reported". The regexes are, from top to bottom:

- `[A-Za-z][_A-Za-z\d]*`
- `_?[a-z][A-Za-z\d]*`
- `[a-z][A-Za-z\d]*`

(You can edit or disable these if you don't like them.)

When combined, these sort of cover all the rules in [this page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/coding-conventions.html#names-for-backing-properties), except perhaps the one about "Names of properties holding references to singleton objects can use the same naming style as object declarations" because static analysis can't reliably determine whether something is a "singleton object".

As you discovered, however, these also adds in other "recommendations" not mentioned in that page, such as private properties in classes should not start with a capital. That said, I don't think that page is supposed to be an exhaustive list of all the recommendations anyway. That page even recommends you to use these inspections to verify that the code follows the style guide:

> #### Verify that your code follows the style guide
>
> 1. Go to Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections | General.
> 2. Switch on Incorrect formatting inspection. **Additional inspections that verify other issues described in the style guide (such as naming
>    conventions) are enabled by default.**

Comment: That they don't cover "Names of properties holding references to singleton objects can use the same naming style as object declarations" (including UPPER_CASE) seems like a bug to me. What do you think?

Comment: @Jarl Well, IntelliJ can't figure out whether something is a "singleton object" just by static analysis, if your definition of "singleton object" is "any class that only has one instance". Though re-reading it, I think it is possible that the `PersonComparator` example is supposed to be in an `object` (where else would you declare a comparator, right?), and "singleton object" just means anything declared in an `object`, rather than the more general definition of "any class that only has one instance". It's not very clearly written IMO. I would just trust IntelliJ.

Comment: I agree with your interpretation of what they are *trying* to say.
Still this doesn't change the fact that if I create an instance of a class on a file or companion-object level that never changes in any way I would like to use UPPER_CASE. And I can only do that on a file level if the value isn't private. It's weird.

Instead object property naming convention should apply there as well.

Comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-56802/IntelliJ-IDEA-suggest-change-to-UPPERCASE-name-unless-private-is-removed